# How to proceed further if a link is opened in new tab selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on a selenium project in Python where I am automating an online product ordering from https://www.flipkart.com/. I searched for a product(protein supplement in my case). Now when I am clicking on that product, details are now opening in a new tab with buying option there. But I don't have access to the DOM of that tab because I was working with the main page only. I am attaching two images along with code so that you can get my point.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrCM7.png)

**This is my code where I automated the process to click on the product-**

```
def select_product(self):
    
    element = self.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='_4ddWXP']")
    self.refresh()
    try :
        element[0].click()
    except StaleElementReferenceException :
        element = self.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='_4ddWXP']")
        element[0].click()
```

**Please tell me how to proceed further. My main aim is to order that product.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to `new tab` in order to proceed further. The below `code` you can `write` once you `click on product` which will land you on `new tab`.

```
all_handles = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(all_handles[1])
```

`new tab` will have different `handle`, so Selenium has to switch to `new tab`.

Comment: It is automatically sending me to new tab. My question is like how I proceed further. I don't have the access to the HTML of that page

Comment: read my answer again, I have explained the same thing. to get access of HTML in new tab you have to switch. Also for switching you do not need HTML

Comment: @ANIMESHSINGH it will take you to the new tab visibly but internally you have to switch the driver focus to new tab so for that you need to use `window_handles`